# Do I have to keep the male in the living room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I want to move the guy out so he can work again, but I need to know if the female will not become pregnant if I do this.

Answer (score 3):

The female gets pregnant right away after they mate, so you can get him (and her) out of the Living Quarters after this.

Answer (score 3):

Wait until the female is wearing a yellow shirt and limping around slowly. Then you can send each of them off to work again.